# Double equals (Not equality) during assigning Java

Tags: java

When I tried searching this I would just get things on equality.

When I was reading through some documentation for navigation in Android I had come across something I had never seen before. I came across this:

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
```

It almost looks like something you can do in JavaScript where you can take the first not-null variable and assign it to a variable.

In JavaScript I would do this:

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle || getTitle();
```

And it would return the first not null, in Java, is this double equals usage the equivalent in Java?

What is this type of expression called?

Comment: This is known as [chained assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Chained_assignment).

Answer (score 3):

Looking more into it, it is actually nothing like what I thought it was, it is simply the assignment operator.

As I found here: http://www.rapidprogramming.com/tutorial/JAVA-Operators-Logical-Conditional-Assignment--28

You can assign a value to more then one variable at once using it.

For example:

```
int num = 20000;

int p, q, r, s;

p = q = r = s = num;
```

(Taken from the site)

Comment: You can assign a value to more then one variable at once because the value of an assignment is the value that was assigned. Therefore you can use the value of an assignment as a rvalue of another assignment and so on.